# regex help: how to match only either pattern in a regex that contains "or" operator?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using php's `preg_replace()`.

Basically I have 2 possibilities of a string to match:

1. Hello Real World
2. Greetings

Here's what I wish to accomplish:

1. `Hello </span>Real World`
2. `Gree</span>tings`

**Rule** explained: if a string contains space(s), insert `</span>` right after the first space character. If a string contains no space(a word), insert `</span>` right at the middle(+/- if odd character count) of the string.

So far, I have came up with a long working solution:

```
<?php 
$str = "Hello Real World";
echo preg_match("/ /", $str) ? preg_replace("/ /", " </span>", $str, 1) : preg_replace("/.{" . round(strlen($str)/2) . "}/", "$0</span>", $str, 1);
?>
```

However, I believe it can be accomplished with a much shorter and elegant regex with only a single `preg_replace()` call.

Any idea how to do it with only single preg_replace() call? e.g.:

```
preg_replace("/ |.{" . round(strlen($str)/2) . "}/", "$0</span>", $str, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression engine doesn't know ahead of time if there is a space in the string.  You don't need regular expressions to do this at all, although you do need multiple functions:

```
$pos = strpos($str, ' ');
if ($pos === false) {
   //No space found
   $pos = intval(strlen($str) / 2);
}
else {
   //we want to insert *after* the space
   $pos++;
}
$str = substr_replace($str, '</span>', $pos, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up using: `echo substr_replace($str, '</span>', (strpos($str, ' ') === false ? intval(strlen($str)/3) : strpos($str, ' ')), 0);` because I really need a one-liner.

Comment: Well okay, but note that you end up calling `strpos` twice

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not a shorter and elegant way to do what you're thinking.  Regexes are not a magic tool that can perform unlimited feats on strings.

The one thing I would suggest is that you not use regexes everywhere, because you don't need a regex to find a space.

```
echo strpos( ' ', $str ) === FALSE
    ? str_replace ( ' ', '</span>', $str, 1 ) /* Only replace 1 occurrence */
    : preg_replace("/.{" . round(strlen($str)/2) . "}/", "$0</span>", $str, 1);
```

Like [the docs for `str_replace` says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), "if you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace()."